# Anaconda and different python builds for the same python version

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Some time ago when i wanted to install a package using Conda in Anaconda python distribution i saw that Conda wants to update the python package from 2.7.10-0 to 2.7.10-1. It's the same python version (2.7.10 in this case).

Checking the channel's content I see there are multiple packages for the same python version:

```
python-2.7.10-0.tar.bz2     18.3M   
python-2.7.10-1.tar.bz2     16.7M   
python-2.7.10-3.tar.bz2     16.7M   
...
```

So what is the difference between these builds and how can i prevent them to be updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing there are [build numbers](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/building/meta-yaml.html#build-number-and-string).

They're usually used to fix a build of the same version of a package.

For example, imagine you have built this python version accidentally as a [pydebug](https://docs.python.org/devguide/setup.html#compiling-for-debugging) build. However, that's not what you want since it will lead to crashes in users of this package if they're not away that this is a *pydebug* build.
In this case you should rebuild the package (correctly this time), increment the *build number* and re-upload it.

> So what is the difference between these builds?

You can't easily know the difference, unless Continuum provides a changelog for each build of python they provide (which I sincerely doubt).

To install a package with a specific build number you could do: `conda install "python=2.7.10 0"`. The `0` means the **build number**.

**I don't know if this syntax is officially supported**, however it worked the last time  I used it.

> how can i prevent them to be updated?

First I would have to know what is your workflow.

If you're asking about the command-line, I don't think that is possible.

If you're asking about using `environment.yml` files you can *pin* a package to a specific version (including the build number) using a similar syntax of `conda install`.

Comment: Hi, this is clear to me but where can i find the information whats different in these packages? And how can conda be force to not update these packages?

Comment: Hi, the syntax you supplied didnt work for me on conda 3.7.0. But it seems to work for conda > 4. Thanks

Comment: @maggie sorry, I've written it wrong. I've edited the question to fix this

Comment: In the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48128029/installing-specific-build-of-an-anaconda-package) question, the format is:   
`conda install <package_name>=<version>=<build_string>`
For you this would become:
`conda install python=2.7.10=0`