# Installing specific BUILD of an anaconda package

Tags: python, anaconda

Is there any way to install a specific build+version of a package in Anaconda? Stack Overflow post "[anaconda/conda - install a specific package version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38411942/anaconda-conda-install-a-specific-package-version)" shows how to install a specific *version* of the package. But look below--there are several pillow packages version 4.2.1 that has "py27" prefix on it.

Background: I am scratching my head to figure the meaning of "conda search" output. For example, on my installation, `conda search pillow` gives:

```
pillow                       2.1.0                    py26_0  defaults
...
                          *  3.3.1                    py27_0  defaults        
                             3.3.1                    py34_0  defaults        
                             3.3.1                    py35_0  defaults        
....
                             4.2.1                    py27_0  defaults        
                             4.2.1                    py35_0  defaults        
                             4.2.1                    py36_0  defaults        
                             4.2.1            py27h7cd2321_0  defaults        
                             4.2.1            py35h03abc04_0  defaults        
                             4.2.1            py36h9119f52_0  defaults        
                             4.3.0            py35h550890c_1  defaults        
                             4.3.0            py27h353bd0c_1  defaults        
                             4.3.0            py36h6f462bf_1  defaults
```

I understand the meaning of 2.1.0, 3.3.1, and so on--the version numbers. But what do `py27_0` and `defaults` mean? More mind boggling was new appearance of the trailing hex numbers like in `py27h7cd2321_0` . After researching some more:

https://www.anaconda.com/blog/developer-blog/package-better-conda-build-3/

tells me that that's a new way to encode the specific build of the package.

So back to my question: given that I'm still on Python 2.7 line of anaconda, how do we choose the `py27_0` build instead of the other one (`py27h7cd2321_0`) when we do `conda install`?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

The column with `py27_0` is what build/version of python it is for. The column with `defaults` is to indicate which Anaconda channel it falls under. Different users or organizations can have their own channels but the default channel is `defaults` and another popular channel is `conda-forge`.

The way you install any specific version from that information is:

```
conda install pillow=4.2.1=py27h7cd2321_0
```

Which is of the format

```
conda install <package_name>=<version>=<build_string>
```

If you want to choose which channel (otherwise `defaults` is chosen by default):

```
conda install -c <channel> <package_name>=<version>=<build_string>
```

Comment: You didn't respond to the question "how do we choose the `py27_0` build instead of the other one (`py27h7cd2321_0`)", what is the difference?

Comment: As I understood it, the full question was "how do we choose the `py27_0` build instead of the other one (`py27h7cd2321_0`) **when we do conda install**?". That is what I answered. However if you mean "But what do `py27_0` or `py27h7cd2321_0` mean?", OP answered it themselves. Further information can be found [here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/variants.html#differentiating-packages-built-with-different-variants).